# Prove $(\frac{a}{b-c})^2+(\frac{b}{c-a})^2+(\frac{c}{a-b})^2 \geq 2$

Tags: inequality, summation, proof-writing, symmetric-polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $a, b, c$ are distinct real numbers, prove that

$(\frac{a}{b-c})^2+(\frac{b}{c-a})^2+(\frac{c}{a-b})^2 \geq 2$

I thought of using AM-GM but that is surely not getting me anywhere ( Maybe some step before i can do AM-GM ?)

I thought of applying AM-GM but that clearly doesnt give anything. Then i thought if a assuming \txtWloga>b>c, that would make the first time greater than 1 so if only i could show that the sumof the other two terms is ≥1 i'd be done but ofc i couldn't progress further from there.

Thanks.

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: I thought of applying AM-GM but that clearly doesnt give anything. Then i thought if a assuming Wlog $a>b>c$, that would make the first time greater than 1 so if only i could show that the sumof the other two terms is $\geq1$ i'd be done but ofc i couldn't progress further from there. Sorry for not mentioning this in the post. Also extremely sorry if i missed anything really obvious as m not really good at it but m still trying hard.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before, e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2724332/proving-expression-geq-2-where-variables-are-x-y-z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{(b-c)^2}=\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b-c}\right)^2-2\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{(b-c)(c-a)}=$$
$$=\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b-c}\right)^2-2\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab(a-b)}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a-b)}=\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b-c}\right)^2+2\geq2.$$

Comment: You answered an identical question before: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2724454.

Comment: Fantastic Solution! Could you please provide some tips on attacking inequalities O' inequalities God?

Comment: @Aayam Mathur Just always prove inequalities. It's a beautiful section. You'll know very many ways to proving inequalities. I think the best place to learn inequalities it's here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6_inequalities Just read it.

Comment: Will surely have a look at those questions! So practice is the key eh? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note
$$ \sum a(2a-b-c)=2(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca),$$
and
$$\sum (b-c)^2(2a-b-c)^2=2(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)^2.$$
Therefore, according to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$\sum \frac{a^2}{(b-c)^2} \geqslant \frac{\left[a(2a-b-c)+b(2b-c-a)+c(2c-a-b)\right] ^2}{(b-c)^2(2a-b-c)^2+(c-a)^2(2b-c-a)^2+(a-b)^2(2c-a-b)^2}=2.$$

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, this question is a duplicate. Since you have a new solution, I would appreciate it if you post your answer in the [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2724332/proving-expression-geq-2-where-variables-are-x-y-z).